# Pickle - cPickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '?'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle

I was trying to load data by using this repository (uses some **Python 2** originally): 
https://github.com/hashbangCoder/Text-Summarization

However I got an pickling error (using **Python 2.7**, I tried also **Python2.6** with the same result):

```
>>> import cPickle as pickle
>>> pickle.load(open('train.bin', 'rb'))
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
cPickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '?'.
```

I tried also with **Python3** but without success (same for `_pickle`):

```
import pickle
pickle.load(open(path, 'rb'))
```

**Error:**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnpicklingError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-0129e43fa781> in <module>()
----> 1 data = pickle.load(open(path, 'rb'), encoding='utf8')

UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\xd9'.
```

There are plenty of questions out there dealing with this error, but I haven't found anything that solves my problem.

I tried also on different systems and downloaded it twice to be sure that the file wasn't corrupted during the download. I'm also getting similar errors for the other files. 
So I guess it may be some kind of version or encoding problem here?

Any idea what I can try to load the file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This looks like an encoding issue. When I look at the file, it does not seem to actually contain a `\xd9' and unpickles without issues in Python 2 and 3. What is your environment, how did you put the file locally, what is its encoding?

Answer (score 3):

I recently had this issue when trying to unpickle a file... try using `joblib` instead:

```
fname = 'Path_to_filename.pkl'
model = joblib.load(open(fname, 'rb'))
```

Otherwise - it is likely a corrupted file.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue.
I transferred files using disk.
They were not properly saved. 
The issue disappeared after I verified the save to disk.

Answer (score 0):

i also had the same problem coz file was not correctly stored on the disk it was corrupted redownloaded it error was gone

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use a file with **PKL extension** then it gonna work

```
train_data = pickle.load(open('train_data.pkl','rb'))
```